# getting extra in activityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, camera, android-camera

I have been googleling but so far no luck.
I have an app in which I start an ActivityForResult and in it I put a String extra.

Edit
I couldn't post a complex code since I was on my table, I just got on my laptop so here the code

the ActivityForResult:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
    super.onCreate(saved);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);
    a = new AQuery(this);
    output = getIntent().getExtras().getString("output");//Here, nothing is passed!!!!!!!!
    //Log.d("out",output);
    /** Check if this device has a camera */
    if (this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)){
        text ="yes";
         //now we check the cam features
        if(this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT))
            front ="yes";
        if(this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH))
            flash = "yes";
        if(this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA))
            back= "yes";
    }else{
            text = "This device does not have a camera";
            //---set the data to pass back---
            data.putExtra("vid",text);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
             //---close the activity---
             finish();
    }
    if (c != null) {
        c.release();
        c = null;
    } 
    m = new MediaRecorder();
    c = getCameraInstance(this);

    Camera.Parameters parameters = 
            c.getParameters();

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, c);
    int orien =getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if(orien ==1){
        parameters.setRotation(0); // set rotation to save the picture
        c.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        parameters.setPictureSize(640, 480);
        PIC_ORIENTATION = "landscape";
    }else{
        parameters.setRotation(0); // set rotation to save the picture
        c.setDisplayOrientation(0);
        parameters.setPictureSize(640, 480);
        PIC_ORIENTATION = "portrait";
    }
    if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() < 2) {
        //TODO
    }
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
    c.setParameters(parameters);
    m.setCamera(c);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
}
```

and for the launching intent

```
cam.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Mess.this,Cam.class);
                    i.putExtra("output", vids);
                    startActivityForResult(i,2);
                    dialog.cancel();//TODO

                }

            });
```

Nothing is passed in value.. it is just null...
This is the activityForResult... but in just Activity, I get the passed value.

Comment: From where are you trying to retrieve the data? Please post the code related to both activities

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is passed"? Is the Extras bundle null? Is the `getString()` result null?

Comment: For future reference, you should post more complete example code. Particularly, you should give the surrounding class and method that contains the code.

Comment: `startActivityForResult(i,2);` What does the 2 mean?

Comment: Also you can probably remove the camera code since it has nothing to do with your current question.

Answer (score 1):

You do this to put the value:

```
i.putExtra("string","value");
```

Then you do this to get the value:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("value");
```

The second line should be

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("string");
```

Comment: thanks for the help, my bad, I was on my tablet so I typed the code in a hurry, I just edited my question from my laptop

Answer (score 0):

After some well deserved rest, I got my head cleaned and looked at the code... The problem is that I wasn't initializing the output string, thus when puting the extra in the Intent, it was an unset String... Now got it working